# Can't use `source` from cron?

Tags: bash, cron, docker

I'm setting up a docker container which requires a cronjob to do a backup using `awscli`.

I'm having a problem with the cron job being able to access the environment variables of the docker container. As I work around on startup I print all environment variables to a file `printenv > /env`.

When I try to use `source` from the cron job (I have tried both directly in crontab and in a script called by crontab) it doesn't seem to work.

I made a simplified version of my project to demonstrate the issue *(including `rsyslog` for logging)*:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM debian:jessie

# Install aws and cron
RUN apt-get -yqq update
RUN apt-get install -yqq awscli cron rsyslog

# Create cron job
ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Output environment variables to file
# Then start cron and watch log
CMD printenv > /env && cron && service rsyslog start && tail -F /var/log/*
```

**crontab:**

```
# Every 3 minutes try to source /env and run `aws s3 ls`.
*/3 * * * * root /usr/bin/env bash & source /env & aws s3 ls >> /test 2>&1
```

When I start the container I can see `/env` was created with my variables but it never gets sourced.

Comment: What are you doing?  Do you have a file in your root directory named `source`?  I'm pretty sure it should just be `source` and not `/source`

Comment: Also do you know you are creating a file in your root directory named `env` and not using the actual `env` command?

Comment: @Jesse_b sorry typo fixed.

Comment: @Jesse_b  Cron doesn't have access to my environment variables so I'm outputting them to a file on startup and sourcing them in the cronjob.

Comment: @Jesse_b creating? I assumed there's a file called `/env` that has the environment variables that need to be sourced. Is that wrong Philip?

Comment: @terdon exactly

Comment: he's creating it with this line: `printenv > /env` and if it already exists he's overwriting it.  I don't see much of an issue with creating such file but the fact that it is being created in the root directory makes it seem like an oversight.

Comment: @Jesse_b yes, but that has nothing to do with the command `env`. The command is being used to find `bash` in the current `$PATH` and the *file* `/env` has the variables that need to be sourced.

Comment: @Jesse_b this is a simplification of my actual project to demonstrate the problem in the shortest possible script. My actual script is longer. Using `/env` saves space.

Comment: Understood.  In that case it's still seems unnecessary, but also how am I the only person that takes issue with these files being saved in `/`?

Comment: @Jesse_b  "*My actual script is longer. Using /env saves space*". The files could be at `/some/random/path/here/env` for all we know, this is just an example.

Comment: @terdon, I read that...don't see how it changes anything I said though...The way I originally read this script was as if someone was doing this:  `cat $file | /grep 'string'` it's not unreasonable to ask if a slash in front of a well known command name is a mistake.  Especially since the slash in front of `source` was a mistake too.

Comment: @Jesse_b the file isn't actually stored in `/` so there is no issue to be taken with files being saved in `/`, because no files are being saved in `/`. Using `/env` *in the question* saves space since it avoids needing to write out a long path. We have no idea where the files actually are and that's not really relevant to the main issue of the question anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, the command's (well, shell builtin's) name is `source`. Unless you have written a script called `source` and put it in `/`, you want `source` and not `/source`.

The next issue is that `cron` usually uses whatever you have as `/bin/sh` and `source` is a bashism (or other such more complex shells). The portable, [POSIX-compliant command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) for sourcing a file is `.`. So, try that instead of `source`:

```
*/3 * * * * root /usr/bin/env bash & . /env & aws s3 ls >> /test 2>&1
```

Also, I don't quite understand what that is supposed to be doing. What's the point of starting a bash session and sending it to the background? If you want to use bash to run the subsequent commands, you'd need:

```
*/3 * * * * root /usr/bin/env bash -c '. /env && aws s3 ls' >> /test 2>&1
```

I also changed the `&` to `&&` since sourcing in the background is pointless as far as I can see.

Comment: I tried your original and suggestion and it didn't work. I'm going to re-build with your update and see if that works.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride if you mean the first one with `root /usr/bin/env bash &`, then that won't work, no. You're just sending a bash instance to the background. If the second one also fails, please explain exactly *how* it fails since "doesn't work" isn't very informative.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride if `&&` breaks, that means the source failed yes. Most likely because you're not using `bash` so you need to do `.`. But running `. file &` (sourcing in the background) will never work because backgrounded commands run in their own subshell, so the variables you sourced will only be available there. If you want to run the second command even if the first failed, use `;`, but don't use `&` here.

Comment: sorry I spoke too soon and deleted my comment right after

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride I know, but I wanted to explain why `&` will always be wrong here.

Comment: The issue is actually that despite my environment variables being set, (I switched the aws command to `echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION >> /test` to confirm), `awscli` doesn't seem to see them. Though normally it works in the main terminal of Docker and recommends authenticating via environment variables http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html 

The problem is out of the scope of this question, so I will mark as solved and maybe post something on their github.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride they are set, but are they exported? That's a big difference. That you can see the variable when you echo it doesn't mean that child processes inherit it. Compare `foo='bar'; bash -c 'echo $foo'` and `export foo='bar'; bash -c 'echo $foo'` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.` since as [terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398107) already mentioned that cron uses `/bin/sh` by default and doesn't recognize `source` command sometimes.

I wanted to add one more thing: you can't source file and use that in second command, so something like this might not work:

```
* * * * * source ~/.bash_profile
* * * * * do some stuff with bash_variables
```

Because each line is session itself so sourced variables in first command will not be available in later commands.
You would have to do something like this:

```
* * * * * source ~/.bash_variable && do some stuff with bash_variables
```

Comment: @chaos: Is it possible to source for all commands? eg `. /path/env \n * * * * * $MYENV/cmd param1 param2`