# CLASSPATH in crontab

Tags: cron

I am having trouble getting my Java program to run from `cron`.  I am able to recreate the problem, using a simple example, as explained below:

In the file `/path/to/javaenv.txt` I define my `CLASSPATH` variable as follows:

```
export CLASSPATH=\
"/path/to/dir1":\
"/path/to/dir2":\
"/path/to/dirn":\
"/path/to/jar1":\
"/path/to/jar2":\
"/path/to/jarn"
```

From the command line I am able to execute the Java program quite easily by doing something like this:

```
source "/path/to/javaenv.txt" && java pkgName.ClassName cmd-line-params > /tmp/test-$(date +%s).txt 2>&1
```

However, the job does not get executed from `cron`, eventhough my `crontab` has the following entry:

```
* * * * * source "/path/to/javaenv.txt" && java pkgName.ClassName cmd-line-params > /tmp/test-$(date +%s).txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues in your cron schedule:

1. The `%` character has a special meaning in crontabs, and must be escaped as `\%` if you want to use it as you would ordinary use it on the command line.  See [How can I execute `date` inside of a crontab job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29578)
2. The `source` command may not be supported by the shell that interprets the command in the schedule.  This depends on what shell `/bin/sh` is on your system (`dash` does not support the non-standard `source` command).  Make sure to use `.` (a dot) in place of `source` to make your command portable. See e.g. [Can't use `source` from cron?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398106)
3. A possible third issue is whether or not the `java` executable is found or not, and this depends on the value of the `PATH` variable in the cron environment.  If you want to ensure that `java` is found, set `PATH` to include the correct directory in the crontab, the environment file you source, or invoke the executable with its absolute path.